# Jquery Detect First Mouse Movement

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to detect the first occurrence of a mouse movement so I can target human visitors with jquery affects. Any leads on how I might accomplish this. I'd also like to do this without targeting class names or object ids... so a blanked target on the  tag should do. Any advice?

Comment: Well, you can move the mouse without "being human". See AutoIt for example, which moves the mouse for you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$('body').one('mousemove', function() { .... } );
```

This will look for mouse movement anywhere, but will only do it once.

Note: This isn't exactly a reliable method, smartphones don't have mice. And a non-human program can still move the mouse.

But it does answer your question.

Comment: Man... that jQuery... all the features you want, even if you didn't know you wanted them. This post just taught me about .one( )

Comment: This ends up being the best solution, mixed with jfriends: the end code looked something like this:

jQuery(document).one('mousemove',function(){
action here...
});

Question though, could I do the same with the first scroll down instance?

Comment: Sure, just replace `'mousemove'` with `'scroll'`. I'm not sure if you should bind it to document though.

Answer (score 1):

Mouse events bubble to the document unless blocked.  You can generally see them with a mousemove handler on the document:

```
document.onmousemove = function() {console.log("mousemove");}
```

or in jQuery:

```
$(document).mousemove(function() {
    // put your code here
});
```

If you only want to see a few initial mouse movements, you can remove the event handler at the desired time or just ignore future events once you've detected a human.

Why would you bother not running animations when it's not a human?  Does it cost you something?  Animation is a client-side thing, right?  Chances are, if it's not a human (like a bot of some type), it isn't running javascript anyway.

Comment: Hi I'm trying out all the options, would this cause document.onmousemove to contain a return 0 or 1?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.  What does this mean "to contain a return 0 or 1"?

Comment: I was having trouble trying to figure out how to use the javascript method in a conditional function. The jQuery makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your purpose corretly, but how about something like this:

```
var detectMouseMovement = function() {
    $(document).unbind('mousemove', detectMouseMovement);

    // do whatever you need to do..
};

$(document).bind('mousemove', detectMouseMovement);
```